# Setting a Cookie on Session Start in ASP.Net if QueryString Variable Present

Tags: asp.net

I am looking to more accurately track a marketing plan that is sending traffic to my asp.net website. Currently, I have coded into individually pages to look for the referral querystring parameter "gclid".

Example: http://example.com/landingpage.aspx?gclid=[vlue]

I was hoping there was a way to make this process global for any landing page in my site and set a cookie equal to the value of gclid only when it is found in the querystring of a landing page.

Is this something that done reliably with Session_OnStart?

Answer (score 2):

The `Session_Start` event in the `Global.asax` file is one alternative that you can use for this. See answer by @sh1rts.

But the `Session_Start` event (of course) only fires when a new session is started. Hypothetical situation:

1. A user clicks a link on some other site and arrives on your site
2. `Session_Start` runs and stores the `gclid` value to the new session
3. User goes back to the other site
4. A short while later the user clicks another link and once again comes to your site
5. User already has a session on your site, so `Session_Start` is not triggered again

If the `gclid` is different the second time, the session won't be updated with that value. This may not be a problem in practise, so `Session_Start` may be a solution. If this *could* be a problem, then you can use a different event in `Global.asax` that runs for *every* request. For example `Application_PostAcquireRequestState`:

```
void Application_PostAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var httpApp = sender as HttpApplication;
    if(httpApp != null && httpApp.Context != null && httpApp.Context.Session != null)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpApp.Context.Request.QueryString["gclid"]))
            httpApp.Context.Session["gclid"] = httpApp.Context.Request.QueryString["gclid"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Not to worry, the first visit and gclid value will be relevant for 30 days, so session is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Session_Start is a reliable way to do this.

At this point `HttpContext.Current` will be valid, so you can get to the querystring using `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString`, i.e.

`var gclid = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["gclid"];`